# How to format with commas all the valid numbers in all the columns using datatables?

Tags: datatables

I want to format thousands and millions numbers in all the columns from a table rendered using datatables, however I don't want to change the data on the original table since that data is going to be used for a dynamic chart.

How can I modify just the render of the table and apply that to all the columns?

Answer (score 3):

If someone stumbles with this same need, it is possible to use the columnDefs options initially passed to the dataTable constructor to modify the render side of the datatable without affecting the .data() values.

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [{
            targets: "_all",
            render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                if(type === 'display' && !isNaN(data*1)){
                    return (data*1).toLocaleString();
                }else{
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }]
    });
```

Here is a jsfiddle that illustrates the approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/spookmx/7hhfpnxp/